# what security issues are required for allowing users to store html content to database and to retrieve html content on web

Tags: mysql, upload, download, code-injection

On my website, registered users can write  styled text contents( i am using nicEdit ) and then they can store them in mysql database. I store their contents in  text type field on mysql db.
Then I allowed the users to retrieve their html contents to be shown on user page on the website.
My question is, shall I use mysql injection avoiding techniques before sending users html contents to the mysql database. And when the users retrieve the  html contents on the web what should i do before displaying html contents on the website.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using the php language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the special characters in your `unsafe_variable`, or use a parameterized query to prevent MySQL injection. The parameterized query is considered the better practice, but escaping characters in your variable will require fewer changes.

You'll need to use a HTML-sanitising library with a proper HTML parser for output HTML to user. See for example [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

`htmlspecialchars` will quote all tags in HTML, so user will see just plain text. You can use `strip_tags`, but `strip_tags` does not actually validate the HTML, so it's not recommended.

PDO usage:

```
$unsafe_variable = $_POST["user-input"];
$sth = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (?)");
$sth->bind_param("s", $unsafe_variable);
$sth->execute();
$sth->close();
```

mysqli usage:

```
$unsafe_variable = $_POST["user-input"]
$safe_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_variable);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('" . $safe_variable . "')");
```

Comment: and what about displaying these html contents on the web. shall i use  htmlspecialchars before display.

Comment: User will see just plain text if you use `htmlspecialchars`. You can use Use `strip_tags` to `$allowable_tags` for this.

Comment: thank you very much.Hopefully it will solve my problem and i am gonna try these things.